# Error in implementing Aspect-based sentiment analysis deep learning model

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, keras, sentiment-analysis

I have a task of `Aspect based sentiment analysis` where I have to first predict aspect for each sentence. Aspects are pre-defined & they are in total 19.

I have to implement a `2-layer Neural Network` (for the above task) where the first layer is fully connected & second layer outputs a softmax distribution.
Each sentence is represented by an average of the word vectors. Word vector model which is used is `GoogleNews 300 dimensional wordvec model` [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing ].
So for each sentence I have a 300 dimensional word vector (average of all the 300-dim word vectors of all the words in the sentence).
The output `y` is defined as `y(i) = 1/k` when the sentence has aspect i & total of k aspects
otherwise `y(i)=0`
(Note that - A sentence can have multiple aspects)

To implement above model -
I have in total 1739 sentences & for each of them I have a `300-dim` word vector. So I have a `np.array` `X` of shape `(1739,300)`. Similarly `y` is `np.array` of shape `(1739,19)`.

My code using keras is -

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(output_dim=64, input_dim=300))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(output_dim=19))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=3)
```

This code throws me error -
`Exception: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_4 to have shape (None, 300) but got array with shape (1739, 1)`

I am new to deep learning & keras, so if anybody can throw some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you print out the shapes of X and y. It seems that something went wrong and they have different shape than you expected.

Comment: X.shape is `(1739, )` & y.shape is `(1739,)`

Comment: Shouldn't X has a shape (1739, 300)?

Comment: Yeah thanks @MarcinMożejko for pointing out that. I have again formed `X` & `y` and they have shapes `(1739,300)` & `(1739,19)` respectively now and the above code runs errorfree. Btw did you find anything other abnormal/wrong/weird in my code..or any improvement which you would like to suggest?

Comment: You might check if an overfitting occurs and eventually prevent it by some kind of regularisation.

Comment: Yes it has helped! Thanks.

Comment: So may I write the answer out of it?

Comment: Yeah go ahead..I'll accept it!

Comment: Hey can you share the code? I'm also doing the same project and I am also new to all of this. I can use some mileage. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhilashAwasthi Hello I need your help in Apect-based sentiment analysis can you help me. shubhamt02@gmail.com this is my email ID please feel free to contact me or if you can give me your email ID to contact you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in a wrong dimensionality of your data. It should have shape `(1739, 300)`. Recheck your data preparation as an error probably occured there.